# How to run 10 batch file synchronously and run a second 10 files after all first 10 finished

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have 400 batch files and I want to run 10 batch file synchronously and run a second 10 files after all first 10 finished.

I am using c# and I used process.start() before.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sure, I have some suggestions: 1. Show us what you have done so far, 2. be more specific about what you are asking, rather than asking for a complete solution to your task.

Comment: I want to write an application using .net to fulfill this task. Last time , I used a string cmd to store the command lines and used System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", cmd); to run the batch file.

Comment: @ZhanWang Yes, I gathered that from the C# and .NET tags. What have you tried though and which part are you stuck on? You mention process.start(), which suggests you are thinking of using threads. So what is about threads that is causing you problems? How to detect they have ended? How to loop? etc. You are asking for a complete solution, which is not the purpose of StackOverflow. So narrow down your request to a specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use a [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) Class. You can use Semaphore to limits the number of threads that can access your files.

For example:

```
    private static int _fileProcessed;
    private static Semaphore _pool;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // let say I have a list of file names in an array
        string[] files = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "z" };

        // we only want 10 threads working at one time
        _fileProcessed = 0;
        _pool = new Semaphore(10, 10);

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            _pool.WaitOne();    // wait until I have a free resource 

            Thread t = new Thread(() => ProcessFile(file));
            t.Start();
        }

        // you can either wait here until are theads are done
        // or exit
        // In the example I want to wait
        while (_fileProcessed < files.Length)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("We are done!");
        //Console.ReadLine();
    }


    private static void ProcessFile(string fileName)
    {
        int id = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1:HH:mm:ss.fff} - Working on File: {2}", id, DateTime.Now, fileName);

        // Do Work ....

        // to simulate work getting done - get a number of seconds
        // between 10 & 30 seconds
        Thread.Sleep(GetWorkLength());

        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1:HH:mm:ss.fff} - Worked Completed on file: {2}", id, DateTime.Now, fileName);

        Interlocked.Add(ref _fileProcessed, 1);         
        _pool.Release();
    }

    // Random work length
    private static Random _workLength = new Random();
    private static object _lock = new object();
    private static int GetWorkLength()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return _workLength.Next(10, 30) * 1000;
        }
    }
```

Here is the output:
[image: Output of sample code]

Answer (score 1):

Use Task Parallel Library (TPL) (Task objects) available since .NET 4.0.

Not exactly what you want to do but here is a sample taken from MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx

```
public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      // Create the task object by using an Action(Of Object) to pass in the loop 
      // counter. This produces an unexpected result.
      Task[] taskArray = new Task[10];
      for (int i = 0; i < taskArray.Length; i++) {
         taskArray[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew( (Object obj) => {
                                                 var data = new CustomData() {Name = i, CreationTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks}; 
                                                 data.ThreadNum = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
                                                 Console.WriteLine("Task #{0} created at {1} on thread #{2}.",
                                                                   data.Name, data.CreationTime, data.ThreadNum);
                                               },
                                              i );
      }
      Task.WaitAll(taskArray);     
   }
}
```

Comment: That is cool code, but it doesn't manage the number of task.  OP has 400 files to process, this will just launch all 400 at the same time.

Comment: Start 10, call Task.WaitAll, Start another 10, call Task.WaitAll again...